# Angular route after adding param how we can add sub route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

As an Example : 
  'www.xyz.com/#/indutry/1/subIndustry/2/subSubIndustry/3'

I need to follow this structure how I can ForRoot my Parent route file

Comment: Which angular version you use ?

Comment: angular 4 for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two level nested child routing.

Make sure every route has a unique name.

Your route file.

That basic example, it depends on your app which kind of data you want to show.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {
    path: 'indutry/:indutryId',
    component: IndutryComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'subIndustryone', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {
        path: 'subIndustryone/:subindustryOneId', 
        component: SubIndustryOneComponent,
        children : [
          { path : '', redirectTo: 'subIndustrytwo', pathMatch : 'full' },
          { path : 'subIndustrytwo/:subindustryTwoId', component : SubIndustryTwoComponent },
        ]
      },

    ]
  },
  {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
];
```

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/y1MZX3bEd1LJMN5KGKli?p=preview)

[Blog](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/nested-routes/)